# How to using Left Outer Join or Right Outer Join in Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a query using "=" in where clause, but it is long time to execute when many datas. How to use the Left Outer Join or Right Outer Join or something like that to increase performance 
This is query:

```
select sum(op.quantity * op.unit_amount) into paid_money
from tableA op , tableB ssl, tableC ss, tableD pl, tableE p
where  (op.id = ssl.id and ssL.id = ss.id and ss.type='A') 
    or 
    (op.id = pl.id and pl.id = p.id and p.type='B');
```

Comment: What have you tried so far when trying to include joins ? Where are you stuck?

Comment: You have part-Cartesian joins here. Please post your table structures, sample data and the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not left or right joins.  It is cross joins.  You are doing many unnecessary cartesian products.  I'm guessing this query will never finish.  If it did, you'd get the wrong answer anyway.

Split this into two separate joins and then bring the results together.  Only use the tables you need for each set of joins:

```
select SUM(val) into paid_money
from (select sum(op.quantity * op.unit_amount) as val
      from tableA op , tableB ssl
      where  (op.id = ssl.id and ssL.id = ss.id and ss.type='A')  
      union all
      select sum(op.quantity * op.unit_amount) as val
      from tableA op , tableD pl, tableD p 
      where (op.id = pl.id and pl.id = p.id and p.type='B')
     ) t
```

I haven't fixed your join syntax.  But, you should learn to use the `join` keyword and to put the join conditions in an `on` clause rather than the `where` clause.

Comment: thank you. Your answer gave me an idea and I will try with join keywork

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that this query is returning the required data? To me it looks like it will be returning the cartesian product of op, ssl & ss for each op, pl, p match and vice versa.

I would advise that you split it into two seperate queries, union them together, and then sum over the top.